# Is there a way to configure a JavaEE project to run with a default target runtime?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, configuration

I'm developing a JavaEE system with several applications which consists of many projects (EARs, EJBs, etc).
Whenever I change my runtime target of the Enterprise Server I have to reconfigure each project through Eclipse's wizards, and this takes forever.

For now I use a little script which updates the runtime target manually, although it says [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/tjtargetserver.html):

> The target runtime environment is specified in the org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file in the project's .settings folder. You should not edit this file manually; instead, use the properties window as described in this topic.

Why am I changing the runtime target name?
 1. I've upgraded the runtime target.
 2. Another member of my team co the code from the SVN and he has a different name for the target runtime.

Is there a way to configure the projects to run with a default runtime target, which can be easily configured?

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround for 2: remove the `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` from SVN and put its name in the `svn:ignore` property.

Comment: But then you still need to configure the runtime with the wizard, so I don't see how this solves the issue.

Comment: Just once. Your xml will not be overwritten by your coworkers anymore.